# How to make a module using ctypes cross-platform?

Tags: python, cross-platform, ctypes

I'm writing a python module that uses [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to call C functions. I'm developing on Windows, so I've compiled the C code to a `.dll` file. What's the best way to make my module work smoothly on other platforms?

Would it suffice to compile an additional `.so` file for Unix systems, include both of the shared object files in my module, and have the Python code load one of the two files depending on which system it's running on? If so, how can I compile a Unix-compatible `.so` file on Windows?

Comment: You need a UNIX environment, possibly using a VM.  You need to link with the UNIX python runtime, and you need to test as well.  You also need to make sure in your C that you don't use Windows extensions and you stick to ISO standard C.

Comment: You likely need different .so's for different linux/osx platforms. Its common to bundle the C source with your distribution and build it on the machine as its installed.

Comment: Ah I see. I was hoping I wouldn't have to set up a Unix environment, but that makes sense--thanks. If either of you write up an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You may want to read `CHAPTER 7 - Compiling to C` of _High Performance Python by Micha Gorelick and Ian Ozsvald_